# Angular 6 JQuery Nested attributes Click event not working

Tags: jquery, click, angular6

Adding a  click listener in jQuery isn't working. It seems like nested attributes created in HTML are not picked by jQuery to add the listener

I have tried to add a listener in `ngOnInit()` but it's not working.

HTML Code

```
<ul class="list-unstyled dropdown-content" id="search_dropdown">
  <span *ngFor="let merchant of merchants">
    <li [ngClass]="{ active: isActive(merchant) }">
      <a href="" (click)="selectMerchantFromMenu($event, merchant)">{{merchant.name}}</a>
    </li>
  </span>
</ul>
```

TypeScript Code

```
$(document).ready(() => {
  $("#search_dropdown span li a").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert($(this));
    $("#search_input").val($(this).text());
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you provided is executed only on `document.ready`, and it's happening once, before angular initiates. Placing this code in `ngOnInit` will call the `document.ready` after it's executed, and it will do nothing.

Placing this code outside angular might cause another problem. the query (`$("...")`) is executed once, and the event listener will be applied to the found elements. But `document.ready` will execute the code before angular build the code, so it will find nothing.

I would recommend you take the code outside `document.ready` and use `.on(events, selector, handler)`:

```
ngOnInit() {
  $(document).on("click", "#search_dropdown span li a", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert($(this));
    $("#search_input").val($(this).text());
  });
}
```

But I really recommend you not to use jquery with angular. Angular has everything you might need, without loading an additional library.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this . Jquery has been moved  out and added in angular. Its working fine